# xrander detect only one display

Tags: linux, display, vga, s-video, xrandr

i have a problem, to get a picture on my tv over VGA (and also over S-Video to SCART). I've tried it first over xorg, but without success. After that i tried xrand, but xrander detect only my laptop display, here the output

```
bufka [~] $ xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 1680 x 1050, current 1680 x 1050, maximum 1680 x 1050
default connected 1680x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1680x1050      50.0*    51.0     52.0
```

Any suggestions, how to solve the problem? My video card is Nvidia Geforce 8600M GT, TV is LG M227WPD and OS Ubuntu Lucid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

xrandr is still not working for me, but i've solved the problem with editing of xorg.